# 13.04 Authenticate Fail after install

Tags: 13.04

I have burned an amd64.iso (with all the files showing), and run an installation off of boot after changing bios to permit that and checking the DVD for errors.  Upon completion of the first installation, on reboot I received the message: "Selected boot image did not authenticate."  I requested I hit enter to continue, and doing so shut the laptop down.  I repeated the install removing the prior install, and received the same message.  I am now using the temporary version, and have installed from it again.  I fear a repeat of the message.

```
 I am now working with a computer on which Windows 8 has been deleted and Ubuntu is not working.  What do you suggest is wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to fix this is access your computers bios. From there you must disable secure boot option and use the legacy boot option.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem was the same as mine with the previous ver of Mint, it was an issue solve with Fedora ShIm to rewrite the Windows SLIC.

I saved and linked tha post that saved me, maybe it might help you:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html

The new shim option was the bottom and lengthiest, you  already mentioned you verifiede UEFI is off so it would seem condescending for me to describe it further.

I'll spare the forum from venting my hatred of UEFI and the rest of annoying useless Microsoft DRM.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.